# Clear selected option in ui-select angular

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Anyone know how to clear the selected value of an ui-select box in angular?

I want the functionality of select2 where you have a small x in the selectbox. Doesn't look like it's got the allow-clear method that select2 got.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you are using the select2 theme there is an `allow-clear` option on the `ui-select-match` directive that does this for you. You will have the x on the right and you can clear it by clicking it.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-match

Quick example:

```
<ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
  <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
</ui-select-match>
```

Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DbbUE68QlNLjx97pBZ56?p=preview

This does not currently work using either the bootstrap or selectize theme.

Comment: Do you know how to get that event of clicking the allow clear 'x' button? It would help me to reset the dependent fields

Comment: While this is obvious in the documentation it is pretty annoying that you can only use a boolean but no callback for the allow-clear options... So this is pretty much useless to fire a callback and do something with the related data.

Comment: @GaneshBabu.T.Y https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/dist/select.js#L561  that's the click event you are looking for.  Unfortunately as @ burzum mentioned, the dependent field would require some extra work so you can have more control over it. You can well suggest the ui-select to have all those in a service so you can use decorators or have your own improvement. However that can be a separate question, and the original post only asked for clear the input functionality.

Comment: the selectize theme does not have this option as of now.

Comment: @Jonathan click the Backspace will clear the selected value

Answer (score 37):

You could add a small X button when you display the selection.

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
  <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
  <button class="clear" ng-click="clear($event)">X</button>
</ui-select-match>
```

Then you stop the click event from bubbling up and trigger the open event. And you clear the field by overwriting the selected model.

```
$scope.clear = function($event) {
   $event.stopPropagation(); 
   $scope.country.selected = undefined;
};
```

Here's the plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/qY7MbR

Comment: @exiadbq's solution offers the same feature in a simpler way.

Comment: Yeah that works-- however, I would just like to add, there is now a built-in function so you don't need to add an additional method to the controller.  You can just use `ng-click="$select.clear($event)"` and it would work great ;)  This also goes through updating rendering and callbacks.

Comment: @JonathanReyes hi Jonathan, thank you very much for your comment. works perfecly in my case. =)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using bootstrap, from design perspective, you could also use a fa-remove icon.

Additionally, from usability perspective, you may want to align the remove icon to the left.

The JS:

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select or find...">
    <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="clear($event)">
        <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
    </button>
    <span class="clear-btn-offset">{{$select.selected}}</span>
</ui-select-match>
```

The CSS:

```
.select2 .clear-btn {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: 1px;
}

.clear-btn-offset {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
}
```

On the directive code:

```
$scope.clear = function($event) {
   $event.stopPropagation();
   // Replace the following line with the proper variable
   $scope.country.selected = undefined;
};
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution Igor. Thank you very much. This way looks better than the one suggested by Nic128. I only changed the CSS on `.select2 .clear-btn` because I wanted to see the **X** to the right and I replaced `left: -2px;` for `right: 20px;`. I didn't need to use `.clear-btn-offset` at all.

Comment: Of course you may still use what @exiadbq mentioned, but I personally don't since the element structure and visual style is really better with the explicit button.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: if we used tagging and tagging-label="false" in that case allow-clear functionality not work.**

**Custom clear functionality**

**HTML Code**

```
<ui-select-match placeholder=”Enter table…”>
 <span>{{$select.selected.description || $select.search}}</span>
 <a class=”btn btn-xs btn-link pull-right” ng-click=”clear($event, $select)”><i class=”glyphicon glyphicon-remove”></i></a>
</ui-select-match>
```

**Controller action Code**

```
function clear($event, $select){ 
 //stops click event bubbling
 $event.stopPropagation(); 
 //to allow empty field, in order to force a selection remove the following line
 $select.selected = undefined;
 //reset search query
 $select.search = undefined;
 //focus and open dropdown
 $select.activate();
}
```

Comment: this would be best solution for when u have more than one ui-select filtering one grid. Tested and worked perfectly