# PrimeNg DropDown - User can't clear the value

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm implementing primeNg dropdown component in my Angular2 application.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="listCustomers_itm" placeholder="Selezionare" [(ngModel)]="Customer_itm" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [style]="{'width':'225px'}" filter="filter"  (onChange)="onCustomerSelect($event.value)">
</p-dropdown>
```

All works fine except one annoing thing:

Once time the user has selected an option, **he can't clear the selected value**...

Can you help me?

Comment: Like most dropdowns that doesn't come out of the box, you have to provide your own button, which clears it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think its the only solution without extending the object...

Comment: I think so, to give you an example, check this other stackoverflow post. It's not using primeNg, however you can get some ideas from the plunks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389542/clear-selected-option-in-ui-select-angular

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this, I had to set a placeholder for the dropdown. The code I used is something like:

**template.html**

```
<p-dropdown ...
            placeholder="Select"
            #dropDownThing></p-dropdown>

<button (click)="onButtonClick()"></button>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Dropdown } from "primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown";
...
@ViewChild('dropDownThing')
dropDownThing: Dropdown;
...
onButtonClick() {
    this.dropDownThing.value = <someValueNotInTheDropdown'sList>;
}
...
```

When the code above is run ***without*** a placeholder, the currently-selected option remains selected.

When the code above is run ***with*** a placeholder, the dropdown's value changes to the provided placeholder.

Comment: @ViewChild isn't needed if the only goal is to reset the dropdown value. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Depending on the version of PrimeNg, you can set autoDisplayFirst to false and showClear to true for the same effect, I believe. [showClear]="true" [autoDisplayFirst]="false"

Comment: can use resetFilter(); in case u want to clear via object

Comment: Problem with using placeholder is if you are also using a custom template. Meaning you can't have both. Which is odd, poor engineering.

Comment: This is expected behaviour, as there is this option `autoDisplayFirst` in the docs.
The situation is exactly '5 days of debugging saves 5 minutes of reading the documentaion'.

Answer (score 14):

`[showClear]="true"` OR `editable="true"`
Please add `showClear` property or editable property based on your requirement. This works perfectly for your use case

Comment: Why isn't it documented in primeng documentation?

Comment: This is answer could use more context

Comment: At least now it is documented in primeng, and it works.

Answer (score 6):

To clear the selected dropdown value, just set the selected option to an empty string. For example, here's a drop-down that let's the user select "Last Month" or "Last Week:"

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Initialize drop-down values
    this.ranges = [];
    this.ranges.push({label: 'Last Month', value: 'Last Month'});
    this.ranges.push({label: 'Last Week', value: 'Last Week'});
}

clearDropDown = () => {
  this.selectedRange = '';
};
```

Template:

```
<p-dropdown 
    [options]="ranges" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedRange" 
    placeholder="Select a Date Range">
</p-dropdown>

<button (click)="clearDropDown()">Clear Date Range</button>
```

If 'Last Month' is currently selected in the dropdown, clicking the button will clear the dropdown value (and 'Select a Date Range' will once again be shown).

PS: In this example, 'Select a Date Range' is placeholder text. It is not a selectable option from the dropdown. In most cases, this is what you want.

Comment: if you have one more p-dropdowns the previous filter value wll be set to Select a Date Range, which has to be the value of the filter I selected before, until I clear all values

Answer (score 5):

Had to dig into the source code a little to find, since it's not in the documentation, but the `updateSelectedOption` method did the trick for me. None of the other answers worked in our case. We have a "custom" option (opens a calendar selection tool), which needed to be selectable every time.

template:

```
<p-dropdown #dateDropdown [options]="dateOptions" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"></p-dropdown>
<button (click)="clearSelection(dateDropdown)"></button>
```

component:

```
clearSelection(dropdown) {    
    dropdown.updateSelectedOption(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (primeng version 9.1.3) setting optionLabel fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the properties `showClear` and `autoDisplayFirst` to `true`.

You can find the documentation [here](https://primeng.org/dropdown#api.dropdown.props.autoDisplayFirst)

```
<p-dropdown
    [options]="options"
    [showClear]="true"
    [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add in the options `{label: 'none', value: null}`

Comment: Will not work with custom binding and template.

Answer (score -3):

Since the component is not allowing reset value function, I have implemented a button in the form the clear all the values...

It works properly

Comment: so what does your button do?

Comment: it just reset the binded value, thats it. It set it to null, in this way the user can reset the value