# How to add a none field to a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have this simple dropdown and I have a placeholder that says: **"none"**. However, I want to allow the user to clear what he selected from the dropdown **without having to add another option** in my dropdown. Does anyone know how to accomplish that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-vybgc6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<p-dropdown [options]="options" placeholder="none"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: You will have to add a clear button in order to do this 
Link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287700/primeng-dropdown-user-cant-clear-the-value

Comment: it seems to have showClear flag,  https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-2-2-released/, but I cannot make it work :(

Comment: oh, it worked with primeng@5.2.4, not with the version you used in demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-ba26e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your only choices are to add a 'none' option or to have some other control in the form that will have the action of clearing the value of the dropdown.

See: [PrimeNg DropDown - User can't clear the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287700/primeng-dropdown-user-cant-clear-the-value)